# tail -f, but with line numbers

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, logs, portability

I'm trying to see how many times `foo bar` appears in `/var/log/foo.log` within an arbitrary amount of time on a remote server, but nothing that I've tried so far has worked.

I've already got a timer script that I use to keep track of how long it has been since I started tailing `/var/log/foo.log`, and now I'd just like a way to tell how many times `foo bar` has appeared in the tailed output.

I searched google, but I didn't find anything pertinent within the first 10 pages of results.

Here's what I've tried with frustrating results:

```bash
## works on local machine, but doesn't work as expected on remote
tail -f /var/log/foo.log | grep foo\ bar | sed '='

## works on local, but not remote
tail -f /var/log/foo.log | grep foo\ bar | cat -n -

##  works on local, but not remote
tail -f /var/log/foo.log | grep foo\ bar | awk -F'\n' '{printf "[%d]> ", NR; print $1}'
```

I even tried to write a sed script that'd act like `tail -f`, but I made limited-to-no headway with that.

**NOTE**

the remote server is running an older version of coreutils, and upgrading is an option, but is **NOT** in any way the desired solution.

Comment: In which way does it not work? Try the `--line-buffered` option to `grep`. Or `tail -f ... | awk '/foo bar/{print ++n, $0}'`

Comment: Why it doesn't work on remote? Example: `tail -f /var/log/log.log | awk '{ printf "[%d]> %s\n", NR+1 ,$0; fflush(stdout); }'`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
tail -f | nl
```

works for me and is the first what I thought of - that is if you really want the lines numbered from 1 and not with the real line number from the file watched. Optionally add `grep` if needed to the appropriate place (either before or after `nl`). However, remember that buffering may occur. In my particular case, `grep` has the `--line-buffered` option, but `nl` buffers it's output and doesn't have an option to switch that off. Hence the `tail | nl | grep` combo doesn't really flow nicely.

That said,

```
tail -f | grep -n pattern
```

works for me as well. Numbering starts again from the beginning of the "tailing" rather than beginning of the whole log file.

Comment: the version of grep running on the server doesn't have a `-n` option.

Comment: it does, however, have the long option `--line-number`: `tail -f /var/log/foo.log | grep foo\ bar --line-number` works!

Comment: That's interesting - I haven't checked POSIX as such, but the GNU grep manpage says: *-n is specified by POSIX*.

Answer (score 29):

I think this is better:

```
less -N +F <filepath>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you think its better?

Comment: Shows the line number taking as reference the entire file. tail -f | nl shows the line number taking as reference the first output of tail.

Comment: This is very handy and addresses the OP's *Title* but not their *question*. They wanted to know how many times X appears in a file :P

Answer (score 7):

You can also pipe the output to `less`, it has a line number feature, `-N` which would allow you to scroll back and forth through the log.

```
$ tail -f /var/log/foo.log | less -N
```

#### Example

```
  1 Jan 17 22:11:58 greeneggs fprintd[4323]: ** Message: entering main loop
  2 Jan 17 22:12:01 greeneggs su: (to root) saml on pts/5
  3 Jan 17 22:12:28 greeneggs fprintd[4323]: ** Message: No devices in use, exit
  4 Jan 17 22:12:56 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: 22:12:56 | Git | personal_repo | Checking for remote changes...
  5 Jan 17 22:12:56 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: 22:12:56 | Cmd | personal_repo | git rev-parse HEAD
  6 Jan 17 22:12:56 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: 22:12:56 | Cmd | personal_repo | git ls-remote --heads --exit-code "ssh://sam@sparkleshare.jake      
  6 8us.org/home/sam/SparkleShare/personal_repo.git" master
  7 Jan 17 22:12:58 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: X11 forwarding request failed on channel 1
  8 Jan 17 22:12:58 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: 22:12:58 | Git | personal_repo | No remote changes, local+remote: 532213be48cce3b93cb177d409faa      
  8 03b71d0cfa5
  9 Jan 17 22:13:35 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: 22:13:35 | ListenerTcp | Pinging tcp://notifications.sparkleshare.org:443/
 10 Jan 17 22:13:35 greeneggs gnome-session[1876]: 22:13:35 | ListenerTcp | Received pong from tcp://notifications.sparkleshare.org:443/
```

**NOTE:** Take notice of the output. You may or may not like this feature, but it will take long lines and chop them so that they continue on the next line, but still maintain the same corresponding line number. I find this feature invaluable when parsing log files that are wide! You can see the effect of this feature on lines **6** & **8**.

Comment: This is unclear.  Where is the filename specified? It should be clarified, noting that the output is numbered from 1 starting with the last 10 lines of the filename, as that is the default behavior of `tail`.  As for the long lines, that behavior is toggled within `less` using `-S`.

Answer (score 3):

To grep *new* lines only in the log file as they come with their line number, you could do:

```
{
  initial_lines=$(wc -l)
  tail -n +1 -f | awk -v NR="$initial_lines" '/pattern/{print NR": "$0}'
} < file.log
```

(with `mawk`, you'll want to add the `-Winteractive` option to prevent its *input* (!) buffering).

`wc -l` reads the lines *that were already there* and counts them (the newline characters which means it still works even if the last line is not full yet), and then we `tail -f` the rest (starting from where `wc` stopped reading) and tell `awk` what is the line number of the first one it sees.

Comment: choosing `l` as the variable name made me squint my eyes on $l, thinking it was `$1` ^^ (but as I know (and 100% trust) you, I reread and saw the truth).  Just for curiosity: to avoid some "race condition" between the `wc -l` and the `tail -f` (if the file grows fast, one may discard some lines and thus the NR starts from the wrong number), is it possible to skip `$l` lines instead? (and what limit is there to tail's `-n` in posix & in gnu?). Maybe with a temporary intermediate file?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, `tail -n +1` (read anything from the start position) addresses the race condition concerns. It will read the lines that were not in the file at the time `wc -l` terminated, from the exact position `wc` left it. So NR will have the right position regardless of how many lines have been written in between `wc` ending and `tail` starting. It's if you told `tail` to start from some position relative to the end of the file that  you'd have issues.

Comment: oh, interresting: indeed, the data accumulate into stdin while nothing reads it (between the end of the wc until the start of the head)... I should have realised that. Thx. Now I see why you "<file". clever, as usual :)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, about limitations (which don't apply to `tail -n +1` here), for regular files, most implementations don't have one as they can start from the end and `seek` back until they find the nth newline without having to store more than one buf worth of data in memory. For non-seekable input, that's where you can run into limits. POSIX requires implementations to be able to store at least 10 x LINE_MAX bytes (LINE_MAX being at least 2048). GNU tail has no limit other than memory AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

```
cat -n ARQUIVO.txt | tail -n10
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Specially because the OP wants to use `tail -f` as well as printing the number line.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to number from the beginning you'd need grep -n to apply to all lines.

```
 tail -f -n100000000 filename.log | grep -n ''
```

If you then only wanted to show the last 10 I'd have thought you could re-tail the file:

```
 tail -f -n100000000 filename.log | grep -n '' | tail -n10
```

The first is handy, but shows too much output. I don't know why the second one doesn't work.

Comment: Tail doesn't have a "show all lines" hence my 100000000

Comment: `tail -n +1 -f` to tail from the beginning.

Comment: The second one doesn't work because the right-most `tail` can't output anything until it has seen the last line of its input (how would it know which is the 10th last line?) which will never happen as `tail -f` never stops.

Answer (score 0):

It's the argument `n` or `--lines` (used slightly different ways, see below):

```
$ tail -f -n 25 /path/to/file.txt

$ tail -f --lines=25 /path/to/file.txt
```

See also the help:

```
$ tail --help
```

Comment: The OP wants line numbers, not a number of lines.

Answer (score -1):

The command `cat -n [filename] | tail` will get a quick count and display of the most recent records if that's what you're looking for.

The `-f` switch makes it persistent until escape - which really doesn't sound applicable in your scenario or is redundant.

`wc -l [filename]` will get a count of the lines in the target

`wc -l [filenameprefix]*` will count all lines in all files matching the pattern and even report a summary total at the end.

More complete detail can yield more complete responses.